# React-Rnd one block inside other

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using the react-rnd library to drag and resize blocks. I created a page. It creates a gray container on it and I click on the "add global container" button and a container appears on the field that I can move and resize within the parent gray container
[image]
[image]

in the left corner of the created container there is a purple button, clicking on it, another container will be created inside this container and now the first container will be the parent for the new one created.
[image]

the problem is that I can resize the inner container, but I can not move it, or rather, it moves with the parent component. the inner component will move inside the outer only when the parent component touches the borders of its parent, the gray container
[image]
[image]

in code it looks like this
I have a component , which in itself contains a  component
the Box component is called inside Rdn - this is the block that you see on the screen, Rdn makes it move

```js
type Props = {
  width: string;
  height: string;
  color: string;
};

class BoxWrapper extends React.Component<Props> {
  state = {
    width: "100",
    height: "40",
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
  };

  render() {
    const { width, height, color } = this.props;
    return (
      <Rnd
        size={{ width: this.state.width, height: this.state.height }}
        position={{ x: this.state.x, y: this.state.y }}
        bounds="parent"
        onDragStop={(e: any, d: any) => {
          e.stopPropagation();
          this.setState({ x: d.x, y: d.y });
        }}
        minHeight={16}
        minWidth={16}
        onResize={(
          e: any,
          direction: any,
          ref: any,
          delta: any,
          position: any
        ) => {
          this.setState({
            width: ref.style.width,
            height: ref.style.height,
            ...position,
          });
        }}
      >
        <Box
          x={this.state.x}
          y={this.state.y}
          width={this.state.width}
          height={this.state.height}
          externalHeight={height}
          externalWidth={width}
          color={color}
        />
      </Rnd>
    );
  }
}

export default BoxWrapper;
```

inside the Box component, the purple button is checked and if it is pressed, you need to create the BoxWrapper component

```js
type BoxProps = {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  width: string;
  height: string;
  externalWidth: string;
  externalHeight: string;
  color: string;
};

class Box extends React.Component<BoxProps> {
  state = {
    isClick: false,
    isCreate: false,
  };
  render() {
    const {
      x,
      y,
      width,
      height,
      externalWidth,
      externalHeight,
      color,
    } = this.props;

    const externalH = parseInt(externalHeight);
    const externalW = parseInt(externalWidth);
    const boxWidth = parseInt(width);
    const boxHeight = parseInt(height);
    const xUpperLeft = x;
    const yUpperLeft = y;
    const xUpperRight = x + boxWidth;
    const yUpperRight = y;
    const xDownLeft = x;
    const yDownLeft = y + boxHeight;
    const xDownRight = x + boxWidth;
    const yDownRight = y + boxHeight;

    return (
      <>
        <div
          style={{
            margin: 0,
            height: "100%",
            padding: 0,
            backgroundColor: color,
          }}
        >
          <div className="wrapper">
            <button
              style={{
                width: 0,
                height: "14px",
                borderRadius: "1px",
                backgroundColor: "#fff",
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "center",
                fontSize: 9,
              }}
              onClick={() => this.setState({ isClick: !this.state.isClick })}
            >
              ?
            </button>
            <button
              style={{
                width: 0,
                height: "14px",
                borderRadius: "1px",
                backgroundColor: "#a079ed",
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "center",
                fontSize: 9,
              }}
              onClick={() => this.setState({ isCreate: !this.state.isCreate })}
            />
          </div>
          {this.state.isCreate && (
            <BoxWrapper
              width={width}
              height={height}
              color="#42d5bc"
            />
          )}
        </div>
        {this.state.isClick && (
          <Tooltip
            leftDistance={xUpperLeft}
            topDistance={yUpperLeft}
            rightDistance={externalW - xUpperRight}
            bottomDistanse={externalH - yDownLeft}
          />
        )}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

how can I make it so that I can freely move the inner container without automatically dragging the parent container
I tried in the `onDragStop` method in `Rnd` to specify `event.stopPropafgation()`, but it doesn’t work at all, I don’t know what to do

[this is a working example of my problem the inner Rnd container has the bounds of the bounds = "parent" and the outer one is "window"](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-meadow-juudp?file=/src/app.js)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

problem resolved
you need to replace the `onDragStop` method with `onDrag` and specify
`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`;

[working example with corrections of the previous](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-meadow-juudp?file=/src/index.js:0-205)